# Please recommend books on capture/parsing network video stream(including mjpeg) in windows

Tags: c++, windows, network-programming, video-capture

I'm not stuck by this subject, can you recommend a book really good on this?

**UPDATE**

Actually I tried using curl to fetch a snapshot out of mjpeg stream,but fails,the programe continues to output,can't stop:

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "network path to mjpeg");
res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
printf("%s", res);
curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
```

**UPDATE2**

Found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3921313/how-to-get-a-snapshot-of-network-video-stream-with-curl-in-c-c-in-windows).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think any book addresses all your topics since they are quite varied:

- If by capture you mean "read from socket" you can have a look at winsock or boost asio.
- If by capture you mean "capture from device", you want to look at the DirectShow framework on windows. There is one book available by Mark Pesce AFAIR.
- For purposes of sending video over the network you might want to take a look at RTP/RTCP RFCs:
  https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3550
  An RTP payload for MJPEG can be found in
  https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2435
- A great book about RTP: http://csperkins.org/standards/rtp-book.html

Comment: I've actually read lots of general topics on this,now I'm seeking of a book that has actually details.